# Nodejs Await/Async issue

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a problem with function execution in NodeJs.

I want to wait for each promise in the function because it's not waiting at all and i have incorrect values.

```
async function DistribToken(campid) {
    console.log("DEBUT");
     Campaign.findOne({ campid: campid }).then(
      (campaign) => {
        console.log(campaign);
        if (campaign.tokensend < campaign.nbuser) {
          console.log('Recherche de token');
           User.find().then(
            (user) => {
              len = user.length;
              console.log(len);
              for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                console.log("VERIF TOKEN " + user[i].userid);
                  VerifToken(campid, user[i].userid);
              }
            })
        }else{
          console.log("MAX TOKEN SEND REACHED");
        }
      })
  }


  async function StartToken() {
    Campaign.find().then(
      (campaign) => {
        len = campaign.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          console.log("ANALYZE CAMPAIGN : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname)
          if (campaign[i].status === 'AC') {
            console.log("CAMPAIGN ACTIVE : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname + ': Start Distrib')
             DistribToken(campaign[i].campid);
          }
        }
      }
    ).catch(
      (error) => {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

But it execute on all users DistribToken before starting Veriftoken

I want it to

Start Distrib -> Distrib token User1 -> Verif token User1 -> Distribtoken User2 ...

Someone have an answer for my issue ? :)

Comment: There is no point in using an `async` function when you never use `await` inside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an async function you can await promises, so you replace .then & .catch with a try catch block. You can use the await keyword to await till the promise resolves.

But this is probably not the problem. I think the problem is that you do not await DistribToken & VerifToken (I think VerifToken is also an async function?).

```
async function DistribToken(campid) {
    try {
        let campaign = await Campaign.findOne({ campid: campid });
        console.log(campaign);
        if (campaign.tokensend < campaign.nbuser) {
            console.log('Recherche de token');
            let user = await User.find();
            const len = user.length;
            console.log(len);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                console.log("VERIF TOKEN " + user[i].userid);
                VerifToken(campid, user[i].userid); // you should probably await here too but i don't know if VerifToken returns a Promise
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("MAX TOKEN SEND REACHED");
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}


async function StartToken() {
    try {
        let campaign = await Campaign.find();

        const len = campaign.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            console.log("ANALYZE CAMPAIGN : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname);
            if (campaign[i].status === 'AC') {
                console.log("CAMPAIGN ACTIVE : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname + ': Start Distrib');
                await DistribToken(campaign[i].campid);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: error
        });
    }
}
```

I hoped this helped, good luck! If something is not clear please comment below.

Comment: This is not a good solution, because it serializes the database access, which means it is much slower than it needs to be.

Comment: How do you mean, please explain how to do it correct then. I can learn something out of this too then ;-)

Comment: You do `await` inside your `for` loop, which means the next iteration of the loop will only happen *after* the previous iteration is done. Since the loop body involves a DB access, and DBs are heavily optimized for concurrent access, you are wasting time by doing that. You've effectively turned an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one. The proper way to do this is to use `.map()` and `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this will not work for him because "Start Distrib -> Distrib token User1 -> Verif token User1 -> Distribtoken User2 ...". Thanks I can use this in my own software!

Comment: No... all of these things can absolutely run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I updating your code you can try this

```
async function DistribToken(campid) {
    try {


        console.log("DEBUT");
        let campaign = await Campaign.findOne({ campid: campid }).lean()
        console.log(campaign);
        if (campaign.tokensend < campaign.nbuser) {
            console.log('Recherche de token');
            let user = await User.find().lean()
            len = user.length;
            console.log(len);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                console.log("VERIF TOKEN " + user[i].userid);
                VerifToken(campid, user[i].userid);  // check this needs to be await or not
            }

        } else {
            console.log("MAX TOKEN SEND REACHED");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

}


async function StartToken() {
    try {
        let campaign = await Campaign.find().lean()
        len = campaign.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            console.log("ANALYZE CAMPAIGN : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname)
            if (campaign[i].status === 'AC') {
                console.log("CAMPAIGN ACTIVE : " + campaign[i].campid + ' ' + campaign[i].campname + ': Start Distrib')
                await DistribToken(campaign[i].campid); 
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: error
        });
    }

}
```